# self adjoint question

Tags: linear-algebra

H is an inner product space with inner product $(\cdot,\cdot)$.  Suppose $T\in L(H,H)$ has an adjoint $T^*$.  I'm supposed to show that $T ∘T^*$ and $T^*∘T$ are self adjoint.

I know in order to be self-adjoint, I must show $T=T^*$, so in order to show $T ∘T^*$ is self adjoint, do I need to show $T ∘T^*=T^*∘T$?  Since that would show they are normal , do I show they are self adjoint do I need to show that they are normal?

Comment: You need to show $(T \circ T^*)^* = T \circ T^*$, which is not what you wrote.

Answer (score 2):

You must show
$$(TT^\ast)^\ast = TT^\ast$$
and
$$(T^\ast T)^\ast = T^\ast T$$
Now to see that, first note that $(T^\ast)^\ast = T$ and
$$\langle(TT^\ast)^\ast x, y\rangle = \langle x, TT^\ast y\rangle =\langle T^\ast x, T^\ast y\rangle = \langle (T^\ast)^\ast T^\ast x, y \rangle$$
Where $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ denotes the inner product. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thank you, things are a lot clearer now! I appreciate it.

Comment: Happy to help. If this solved your question, please mark it as answered; else feel free to ask for further clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Note: For $A,B\in L(H,H),\;(A\circ B)^*=B^*\circ A^*$.

Answer (score 1):

We have

$$\langle (T\circ T^*)x,y \rangle=\langle T(T^*x),y \rangle\underbrace{=}_{\mathrm{adjoint- def.}} \langle T^*x,T^*y \rangle\underbrace{=}_{\mathrm{adjoint- def.}}\langle x,T(T^*y) \rangle=\langle x,(T\circ T^*)y \rangle,$$

from where it follows that $T\circ T^*$ is self-adjoint.

Comment: You're welcome.